# Run macros in background while doing something else

Tags: buffers, macro

I have a macro that calls APIs to fetch data based on information in a buffer. Is it possible to have the macro continue execution while I move to another window and work on other buffers?

Comment: It is really a `macro` as a list of keystrokes in a register or it is `vimscript` function running?

Comment: It really is a macro; essentially it goes like this `yypV:!bash^Mk`

Comment: I don't think it is possible. You could be interested to the following [question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/27003/23502).

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt Hmm... Is it possible to run the macro from a function called from a timer somehow.

Comment: I never did but if I was you I would try :-)

Comment: Background tasks need jobs (:help channel). Timers are blocking once they fire, IIRC.

Comment: You should [edit] your question to include the macro. I suggest you also explain what it does and what greater goal you hope to achieve with it. Give some context. Maybe a member of the community will come up with a solution for your original problem.

Comment: The answer is no.

Comment: With sufficient sorcery, it is possible by sending the buffer to opening another vim in the terminal running the selfsame macro :D.